# How to write "start /b /min FeedDemon.exe" in powershell

Tags: powershell

How would I write the following windows command in powershell?

```
start /b /min FeedDemon.exe
```

When I run that on the command line, it minimizes the window fine and works great in a startup script. But in powershell, I cannot get the same results when I try:

```
start-process -FilePath FeedDemon.exe -WindowStyle Minimized
```

*I am still learning powershell (and Windows in general) so please be gentle.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/b` argument to `start` indicates that the program should run without popping a new console window.  The direct translation to powershell would be

```
Start-Process FeedDemon.exe -NoNewWindow -WindowStyle Minimized
```

If that doesn't work, just call it the old fashioned way, from Powershell

```
cmd.exe /c start /b /min FeedDemon.exe
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not realize I could call cmd.exe like that in PowerShell.  Very cool.  thanks for the help!  It's odd that I can't get the window minimization to work using powershell but I am sure there is a more advanced reason why that I'll stumble across some day.

Comment: Yep, all of the exe utils from cmd.exe still work in powershell, including cmd.exe itself :)  Unfortunately, people don't realize this, or think often that it's "bad" to use legacy tools.  I've seen so many questions along the lines of "I relied on tool XYZ for so long and it was so great.  *What is the powershell equivalent?*"  The same tool!  Unless you need detailed output processing and would really benefit from the rich objects emitted by cmdlets.

Comment: From what I checked, Powershell 7.x and 5.1, -NoNewWindow and -WindowStyle are not calling together, it is better to remove -WindowStyle out of your command
References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3